# Get new mail in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I created VBA code for Outlook to extract email address to contact for new mails which arrive to my inbox.

I am getting the selected mail only. Normally when mail come, it will not be selected.

**For Each obj In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection**

Answer (score 0):

You need to tap the Application.NewMailEx event - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx